# Setting elements in .data attribute to zero unpleasant behaivor in scipy.sparse

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I getting unpleasant behavior when I set values in `.data` of `csr_matrix` to zero. Here is an example:

```
from scipy import sparse
a = sparse.csr_matrix([[0,0,2,0], [1,1,0,0],[0,3,0,0]])
```

Output:

```
>>> a.A
array([[0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0]])
>>> a.data
array([2, 1, 1, 3])
>>> a.data[3] = 0   # setting one element to zero
>>> a.A
array([[0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> a.data
array([2, 1, 1, 0]) # however, this zero is still considered part of data
                    # what I would like to see is:
                    # array([2, 1, 1])

>>> a.nnz           # also `nnz` tells me that there 4 non-zero elements 
                    # which is incorrect, I would like 3 as an output
4

>>> a.nonzero()     # nonzero method does follow the behavior I expected
(array([0, 1, 1], dtype=int32), array([2, 0, 1], dtype=int32))
```

What is the best practice in the above situation? Should setting elements of `.data` to zero be avoided? Is `.nnz` unreliable way find number of zeros?

Comment: All sparse matrix implementations I used so far had a fixed sparsity pattern after the matrix was created.  Changing the sparsity pattern later is inefficient.  You can force a new matrix with a new sparsity pattern being created with `sparse.csr_matrix(a.A)`.  `nnz` is meant to give the number of entries consuming space, whether or not they end up being zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sparse matrices in scipy (at least CSC and CSR) have an [`.eliminate_zeros()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.eliminate_zeros.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.eliminate_zeros) method to handle this situations. Run

```
a.eliminate_zeros()
```

every time you mess with `a.data`, and it should take care of it.