# CSR scipy matrix does not update after updating its values

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I have the following code in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
M = csr_matrix(np.ones([2, 2],dtype=np.int32))
print(M)
print(M.data.shape)
for i in range(np.shape(mat)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(mat)[1]):
        if i==j:
            M[i,j] = 0
print(M)
print(M.data.shape)
```

The output of the first 2 prints is:

```
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    1
(4,)
```

The code is changing the value of the same index (i==j) and setting the value to zero.
After executing the loops then the output of the last 2 prints is:

```
  (0, 0)    0
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    0
(4,)
```

If I understand the concept of sparse matrices correctly, it should not be the case. It should not show me the zero values and the output of last 2 prints should be like this:

```
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
(2,)
```

Does anyone have explanation for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I was confused by this too, and asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122024/setting-elements-in-data-attribute-to-zero-unpleasant-behaivor-in-scipy-sparse

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are trying to change elements of the matrix one by one. :)

Ok, it does work that way, though if you changed things the other way (setting a 0 to nonzero) you will get an Efficiency warning.

To keep your kind of change fast, it only changes the value in the `M.data` array, and does not recalculate the indices.  You have to invoke a separate [csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros.html) method the clean up the matrix.  To get best speed call this once at the end of the loop.

There is a [csr_matrix.setdiag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.setdiag.html) method that lets you set the whole diagonal with one call.  It still needs the cleanup.

```
In [1633]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
In [1634]: M
Out[1634]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [1635]: M.A
Out[1635]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)
In [1636]: M.setdiag(0)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
In [1637]: M
Out[1637]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [1638]: M.A
Out[1638]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 0, 5],
       [6, 7, 0]])
In [1639]: M.data
Out[1639]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0])
In [1640]: M.eliminate_zeros()
In [1641]: M
Out[1641]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [1642]: M.data
Out[1642]: array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7])
```