# Efficient way to set elements to zero where mask is True on scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, mask

I have two scipy_sparse_csr_matrix 'a' and scipy_sparse_csr_matrix(boolean) 'mask', and I want to set elements of 'a' to zero where element of mask is True.

for example

```
>>>a
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>>a.todense()
matrix([[0, 0, 3],
        [0, 1, 5],
        [7, 0, 0]])

>>>mask
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.bool_'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>>mask.todense()
matrix([[ True, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then I want to obtain the following result.

```
>>>result
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>>result.todense()
matrix([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [7, 0, 0]])
```

I can do it by operation like

```
result = a - a.multiply(mask)
```

or

```
a -= a.multiply(mask) #I don't care either in-place or copy.
```

But I think above operations are inefficient. Since actual shape of 'a' and 'mask' are 67,108,864 × 2,000,000, these operations take several seconds on high spec server(64 core Xeon cpu, 512GB memory). For example, 'a' has about 30,000,000 non-zero elements, and 'mask' has about 1,800,000 non-zero(True) elements, then above operation take about 2 seconds.

Is there more efficient way to do this?

Conditions are below.

1. a.getnnz() != mask.getnnz()
2. a.shape = mask.shape

Thanks!

Other way(tried)

```
a.data*=~np.array(mask[a.astype(np.bool)]).flatten();a.eliminate_zeros() #This takes twice the time longer than above method.
```

Comment: How do the `nnz` of `a` and `mask` compare?  Besides not being the same.  Are both equally sparse?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @hpaulj! I'm sorry to confuse you. The condition 1 only means 'The number of non-zero(false) elements  of mask is different from the number of elements of a.'.

Answer (score 1):

My initial impression is that this multiply and subtract approach is a reasonable one.  Quite often `sparse` code implements operations as some sort of multiplication, even if the dense equivalents use more direct methods.  The sparse sum over rows or columns uses a matrix multiplication with the appropriate row or column matrix of 1s.  Even row or column indexing uses matrix multiplication (at least on the `csr` format).

Sometimes we can improve on operations by working directly with the matrix attributes (`data`, `indices`, `indptr`).  But that requires a lot more thought and experimentation.

For the dense arrays my first try would be

```
In [611]: a.A*~(mask.A)
Out[611]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [7, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

But there isn't a direct way of doing `not` to a sparse matrix.  If `mask` was indeed sparse, `~mask` would not be.  In your example `mask` has 4 True terms, and 5 False, so a dense version would work just as well:

```
In [612]: nmask=sparse.csr_matrix(~(mask.A))
In [615]: a.multiply(nmask)
Out[615]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

[CSR scipy matrix does not update after updating its values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368109/csr-scipy-matrix-does-not-update-after-updating-its-values) explores setting the diagonal of a sparse matrix to 0.  It is possible to set values of the `data` attribute to 0, and then `eliminate_zeros` once at the end.

The other dense method is

```
In [618]: a1=a.A
In [619]: a1[mask.A]=0
```

This also works in `sparse` - sort of

```
In [622]: a2=a.copy()
In [624]: a2[mask]
Out[624]: matrix([[0, 3, 5, 0]], dtype=int32)
In [625]: a2[mask]=0
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
In [626]: a2
Out[626]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

As noted in the previous question, we need to eliminate the zeros:

```
In [628]: a2.eliminate_zeros()
In [629]: a2
Out[629]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Taking a hint from the sparsity warning let's try the `lil` format

```
In [638]: al=a.tolil()
In [639]: al[mask]
Out[639]: 
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [640]: al[mask]=0
In [641]: al
Out[641]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

It's interesting that `al[mask]` is still sparse, where as `a[mask]` is dense.  The 2 formats use different indexing methods.

At some low level of sparsity, it might be worth iterating over the True (nonzero) elements of `mask`, setting the corresponding terms of `a` to zero directly.

I'm not going to guess as to the relative speeds of these methods.  That needs to be tested on realistic data.

Comment: As you say, I can't apply ~ to the matrix because the actual matrix's shape are too big. I trie'd a[mask]=0, but it took over a minute. I just got an idea of using .data/eliminate_zeros to ses your answer(add to last of question). I'm going to try this on actual data on monday. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the new method on actual data, but it took twice the time longer than multiply method.

Comment: I'm not too surprised.